# Why wasn't "Can anyone recommend a good, free, and online Greek-to-English dictionary?" migrated to Latin.SE?

Tags: discussion

Why hasn't [Can anyone recommend a good, free, and online Greek-to-English dictionary?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20882/23243) been migrated to Latin or Language Learning SE?

Have these Greek-specific questions all been migrated? Undeniably I won't post afresh here for each one!

Comment: Posts can't be migrated once they're older than 3 months.

Comment: ^^ That, and no one flagged it for migration at the time.

Comment: @prash that's impossible because migration flagging only offers meta.ling as target. Can that be selected leaving the choice to the mod? I just came here to ask about that, but to ELU.SE. It's not very userfriendly at the moment.

Comment: never mind. there's ./question/1856 about the issue

Comment: @vectory People usually flag the question for moderator intervention and explain what intervention is required. Don't flag to migrate it to meta.